# Why doesn't ls -la show that current directory is symlink?

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink

This is more of a curiosity, but I noticed `/etc/httpd/logs` is symlinked to `/var/log/httpd`, but when I am inside of `/etc/httpd/logs` and I do `ls -la` I see:

```
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Mar 21 14:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root    4096 Mar 17 03:10 ..
```

Why doesn't the `.` entry show  `lrwx....`?

But when I go to `/etc/httpd` and do `ls -la` I see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Mar  4 17:12 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May I answer with a question?  Assuming you're on a RedHat/CentOS install here...

```
ls /etc/httpd/
  # should return something like:
  # conf  conf.d  logs  modules  run
cd /etc/httpd/logs/
  # Why does this next command fail?
ls ../conf
  # ls: cannot access ../conf: No such file or directory
  # But this next command works?
cd ../conf
```

The short answer is when you're "inside" `/etc/httpd/logs` (the symlink) you're actually inside `/var/log/httpd`, which *is* a directory.

```
cd /etc/httpd/logs/
pwd
  # /etc/httpd/logs
pwd -P
  # /var/log/httpd
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  It is kind of existential :).

Comment: This answered my question (via Google), of why `ls -la /some/symlinked/dir` was not showing the files contained! I just `cd` to that directory, then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

`.` indicates the current directory. Once you `cd` to a symlink, you are in the destination directory. What you are seeing is not an error, or a problem of any kind. This is how symlinks work in unix systems. If you want to see the symlink when you list files, then stay in the parent directory where the actual symlink exists.

Comment: Some shells do keep the history (i.e., how did I land here) around, so if you do `cd symlink; cd ..` you are back where you were.

Comment: Good point, I'm sure this whole premise can be a little confusing to some!

Comment: @vonbrand Because cd is a shell built-in, `..` refers to the shell's concept of "up," based on your "directory history." `ls` is a separate binary, so it interprets `..` to be the directory entry `..` according to the filesystem, which has no way to know it has been symlinked from elsewhere.

Comment: @bonsaiviking, no. The shell could just not care and change directory as told (the Bourne and C shell did). Remembering where we come from is extra work to help (un)confuse the user.

Comment: @vonbrand But the explanation is correct iff your shell acts this way. YSMV (Your Shell May Vary)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cd` is going to "follow" the symlink, but it then sets the `PWD` systems variable with `/etc/httpd/logs`. So that way when you do `cd ..` it uses the PWD variable for reference. `ls` won't. It grabs the physical location of where you're at (/var/log/httpd), just like `/bin/pwd` but shell builtin pwd uses the $PWD variable.

So when you cd into /etc/httpd/logs, you actually go to /var/log/httpd. Thats why when you do `ls -la`, you see . as a directory and not a symlink. Then when you use cd to back out, it remembers that you were in /etc/httpd and uses that as the reference.

If you do `cd -P /etc/httpd/logs`, with -P meaning 'physical', you can see that `cd` sets PWD to /var/log/httpd.

(sorry, my answer was a mix of your question and jscotts question)